# Parse JSON with PHP within a Loop

Tags: php, json, parsing, foreach, decode

How do I parse this JSON with PHP?

```
[{"index":0,"date":" 20120029","title":"testtitle"}
```

There are multiple instances of this. for example:

```
[{"index":0,"date":" 20120029","title":"testtitle"},{"index":1,"date":" 20120007","title":"testtitle"},{"index":2,"date":" 20120006","title":"testtitle"}]
```

When I try an online parser i get this.

```
[
{
"index":0,
"date":" 20120029",
"title":"testtitle"
},
{
"index":1,
"date":" 20120007",
"title":"testtitle"
},
{
 "index":2,
 "date":" 20120006",
 "title":"testtitle"
}
]
```

What i need to know is how would i extract the data and get a variable for `$index`, `$date`, `$title`??

I need this within a foreach. So for every event echo it out?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/json_decode) for that.

```
foreach (json_decode($str, true) as $item) {
    echo $item['title'], "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use `json_decode` to convert the data back into an array/object ([PHP docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)). For the actual traversal I would prefer a usual for loop here.

```
$data = json_decode( '[{"index":0,"date":" 20120029","title":"testtitle"},{"index":1,"date":" 20120007","title":"testtitle"},{"index":2,"date":" 20120006","title":"testtitle"}]', true );

for( $i=0; $i<count($data); $i++ ) {
  echo $data[ $i ][ 'index' ];
  echo $data[ $i ][ 'date' ];
  echo $data[ $i ][ 'title' ];
}
```

But if you want to use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach( $data as $item ) {
  echo $item[ 'index' ];
  echo $item[ 'date' ];
  echo $item[ 'title' ];
}
```

Comment: You forgot to pass the `$assoc` parameter to `json_decode` ... either that or you should use `->` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$data = '[{"index":0,"date":" 20120029","title":"testtitle"},{"index":1,"date":" 20120007","title":"testtitle"},{"index":2,"date":" 20120006","title":"testtitle"}]';

$json = json_decode($data);
foreach($json as $v)
{
    echo $v->index;
    echo $v->date;
    echo $v->title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [josn_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

```
$myNewArrayMadeFromJSON = json_decode($jsonString);

for () {
 // A loop over $myNewArrayMadeFromJSON
}
```